# How to add names to data entries in event viewer <EventData> using c#

Tags: c#, event-viewer

have a requirement to write multiple data items into eventviewer `<eventData>` like below

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"> 
   <System> 
       <Provider Name="Elib" /> 
       <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID> 
       <Level>4</Level> 
       <Task>0</Task> 
       <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
       <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-03T12:42:30.000000000Z" /> 
       <EventRecordID>33</EventRecordID> 
       <Channel>Elib</Channel> 
       <Computer>48vtvs1</Computer> 
       <Security /> 
   </System> 
   <EventData> 
       <Data>Entry1</Data> 
       <Data>Entry2</Data> 
   </EventData> 
</Event>
```

I am able to write multiple entries under `<eventdata>` with the help of below code

```
EventLog.WriteEvent("Application", 
new EventInstance(1001, 0, EventLogEntryType.Information), 
new object[] { "Entry1", "Entry2" });
```

output:

```
<EventData> 
   <Data>Entry1</Data> 
   <Data>Entry2</Data> 
</EventData>
```

but my requirement is to add name attributes to data nodes like below

```
<EventData> 
<Data name="title">Entry1</Data> 
<Data name=Message">Entry2</Data> 
</EventData>
```

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do that. You could try writing XML fragments into there: `new object[]{new XElement("mine", new XElement("sub", new XAttribute("attr", "val")))}`

Comment: that object[] will be the data to <eventdata> so the output as below <EventData>
  <Data><mine> <sub attr="val" /> </mine></Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>. is there any othere way to that? I heared something here can u have a look http://blog.dlgordon.com/2012/06/writing-to-event-log-in-net-right-way.html

Comment: That blog post tells you how to do this "the right way". There is no "simple way".